# Оптимизация UIImageView и UIImageView для Retina дисплея

Tags: objective-c, xcode

В `InterfaceBuilder` есть `UIImageView Fit`. В основном контроллере, по ссылке имею `imageView`, в котором `UIImageView`. Размер `280x280`, в ретине должно быть `560х560`, но я что то делаю не так.

Кусок кода рисует шахматную доску, работая с `imageView`:

```
...
// Инициализируем значения
// Ретина/не ретина 
scl = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
// Размеры поля
width = @(imageView.frame.size.width);
height = width;
// Размер клетки
xstep = @(10);
ystep = @(10);

// Цвета клеток
NSArray *c1 = @[ @0.9, @0.9, @0.9 ];
NSArray *c2 = @[ @0.8, @0.8, @0.8 ];

// Получаем контекст
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.frame.size, NO, scl);
ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

int len1 = @(ceil ( [width intValue] / [xstep intValue] ));
int len2 = @(ceil ( [height intValue] / [ystep intValue] ));

for (int xi = 0; xi < len1; xi++ )
{
    for (int yi = 0; yi < len2; yi++)
    {
        NSArray *c = (xi + yi) % 2 == 0 ? c1 : c2;

        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, [[c objectAtIndex:0] floatValue], [[c objectAtIndex:1] floatValue], [[c objectAtIndex:2] floatValue], 1.0);
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGRectMake( xi*[xstep intValue], yi*[ystep intValue], [xstep intValue], [ystep intValue]));
    }
}

// Записываем сформированный рисунок в наш UIImageView
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

В результате шахматная доска рисуется правильно `28x28` клеток в обычном режиме, но на `retina` их также `28х28`, а должно быть `56х56`.

Comment: > но на retina их также 28х28  
И они б0льшего размера, разумеется?

Comment: Да их тоже 28 и они крупные. Т.е. я имею все то же шахматное поле 280х280, а должно быть 560х560, и соответственно клеток, тоже 56х56.

Comment: @Sergey Vanichkin  как костыльное решение, можно опять же умножить ширину (=длину) поля на 2, тем самым получив нужное кол-во ячеек. Но так делать, наверное, не стоит.  
А вы не пробовали в качестве последнего параметра в `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`указывать `0` - автоматическое определение множителя?

Comment: Да, пробовал, но на результат это не влияет.

Comment: Вообще-то ребята из Apple позаботились о том, чтобы никто не заморачивался какой дисплей у конечного пользователя. Используются points - поэтому и результат на обычном и на ретина одинаковый и должен быть одинаковый.

Comment: Ну так, есть пример как можно текущий код подправить? Поинты как то определеённо надо указать получается?

Comment: Итак, проблема решена достаточно просто, но не уверен что абсолютно правильно. В моём коде выше, 28 клеток рисовались в видимой области а остальные уходили за край UIImageView. Что бы этого избежать, я указал scale для контекста таким образом: CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0/scl, 1.0/scl); В итоге весь контекст смасштабировался и стал помящаться в представление.